# In Application Insights, the client_CountryOrRegion always shows "United States" although my application is in Singapore

Tags: c#, logging, azure-application-insights, .net-5, asp.net5

In Application Insights, the client_CountryOrRegion always shows "United States" although everything is in Singapore (Resource Group, App Services, Application Insights).
I check the App Service Inbound and Outbound IPs, everything is in Singapore

How can I config client_CountryOrRegion to Singapore or the place where my App Services is hosted? Given I am running .Net 5 application.

[image]

Comment: It is the location of the **client**, not of the server. It is an indicator where your visitors come from.

Comment: I dont think so. My App services is in Singapore, and the browser / mobile app are also in Singapore. How can I debug it?

Comment: The client IP 0.0.0.0 is obviously wrong. Can you get the actual public IP address? IP geolocation does not work for private IP address.

Comment: @MichaelC. this is because of IP masking. However, location should be available properly

Answer (score 2):

> How can I config client_CountryOrRegion to Singapore or the place
> where my App Services is hosted? Given I am running .Net 5
> application.

As Peter said It is the location of the **client**, not of the server. It is an indicator where requests come from.

By default, IP addresses are temporarily collected but not stored in [Application Insights.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=net#default-behavior) The basic process is as follows:

When telemetry is sent to Azure, Application Insights uses the IP address to do a geolocation lookup by using  [GeoLite2 from MaxMind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).

Application Insights uses the results of this lookup to populate the fields  `client_City`,  `client_StateOrProvince`, and  `client_CountryOrRegion`. The address is then discarded, and  `0.0.0.0`  is written to the  `client_IP`  field.

The telemetry types are:

- Browser telemetry: We collect the sender's IP address.
- Server telemetry: The Application Insights module collects the client IP address. It is not collected if  `X-Forwarded-For`  is set.
- To learn more about how IP address and geolocation data are collected in Application Insights refer to this  [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection).

You can configure the  `ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer`  to take the IP address from a different header. In some systems, for example, it is moved by a proxy, load balancer, or CDN to  `X-Originating-IP`.  [Learn more](https://apmtips.com/posts/2016-07-05-client-ip-address/).

Comment: I dont think so. My App services is in Singapore, and the browser / mobile app are also in Singapore. How can I debug it?